# Creating a file with python on OpenShift application

Tags: python, module, operating-system, openshift

I'm trying to read a certain file:

```
database = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'database/' + str(address) + '.txt'), 'r+')
```

This works, but whenever the file doesn't exist it returns an error. How can I create an empty .txt file with the OS module? The r+ doesn't seem to work on OpenShift for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file with `a` or `w`. For example:

```
my_file = open('foo.txt', 'a')
```

Which creates `foo.txt` if it does not exist, while not truncating the file if it *does exist*. Alternatively, you can also use:

```
my_file = open('foo.txt', 'w')
```

Which creates `foo.txt` if it does not exist, *but clears the file if it does*.

You can even use the `os` module to do this:

```
import os
my_file = os.open('foo.txt', os.O_CREAT)
os.close(my_file)
```

The `os.O_CREAT` flag will create `foo.txt` if it does not exist.

Comment: Check my updated answer. If it still does not work, please provide *why* it doesn't work. @ThomasW

Comment: errno 2 as before. (FileNotFoundError)

Comment: what you just did is not possible on OpenShift. I tried that before but didn't work - openshift handles file paths differently.

Comment: The basic functionality of the [builtin `open` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) does not change. @ThomasW

Comment: Try using `os.open`. @ThomasW